# How to get contents overly on the bootstrap images

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

**Image 1**
in image 1 i am trying to achieve putting contents on the image as displayed, however i cannot find the specific code, also on hover the div is being zoomed up

[image: Bootstrap content overlay image-1]

**Image 2**
in image 2 i am wanting the contents on the right and left of the image but it should not affect the responsiveness also.

[image: Bootstrap content overlay image-1]

Can anyone please provide me an example where these two things are available i have searched via google but i am getting is on hover!

Comment: There are several ways you can do that. I am sure there is some built in bootstrap functionality that I can't think of from the top of my head but there are 2 other ways: 
1) use the images as backgrounds. That leaves the div free for any other elements.
2) give the picture a frame with relative positioning and use absolutely positioned divs inside with a higher z-index.

Comment: can you send the demo link with code on jsfiddle or if another blog link that have the code, actually i am not an expert in CSS thing just basic knowledge i have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the example code:

HTML:

```
<div class="example example1">
  <p>This uses the image as background</p>
</div>

<div class="example example2">
  <img src="http://cdn2.johnnyseeds.com/images/product/large/1814.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="text">
    This uses the image as background
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.example {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  position: relative;
}
.example1 {
  background-image: url(http://cdn2.johnnyseeds.com/images/product/large/1814.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

.example2 img {
  width: 100%;
}
.text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

And here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3cqw4yre/)

Example 1 uses the background image version. Example 2 uses the absolute divs within the relative positioned frame.

Comment: perfect that's what i needed :)